# Android Media Session API - How to set a url to the METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ART field

Tags: android, kotlin, bitmap, media, android-11

In android media session api an Image can be set using the key MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ART_URI in media session metadata. According to docs it accepts the value as Uri formatted String

```
 /**
 * The artwork for the album of the media's original source as a Uri
 * formatted String. The artwork can be loaded using a combination of
 * {@link ContentResolver#openInputStream} and
 * {@link BitmapFactory#decodeStream}.
 * <p>
 * For the best results, Uris should use the content:// style and support
 * {@link ContentResolver#EXTRA_SIZE} for retrieving scaled artwork through
 * {@link ContentResolver#openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(Uri, String, Bundle)}.
 */
 public static final String METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ART_URI = "android.media.metadata.ALBUM_ART_URI";
```

To set the value

```
  MediaMetadata.Builder()
     .putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, it.name)
     .putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST, it.artist)
     .putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ART_URI, ...)
     .build()
```

So how to use URL or a bitmap object to set this value, without referring to local storages.

Is there a way I can load this image from a online resource, without storing it in the app storage?

Answer (score 0):

We can use METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ART value instead of METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ART_URI to set a bitmap object to the MediaMetadata in Media session API and use it for display purposes
in media session notification.

```
MediaMetadata.Builder()
    ...
    .putBitmap(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ART, getBitmapFromURL(url))



private fun getBitmapFromURL(url : String):Bitmap{
    // Download image as a bitmap using a library like Glide, Picasso etc.
}
```